# General Linear Systems -- Reduced Row Echelon Form

Tags: linear-algebra

For which values of b and c does the following system have (a) no solution? (b) exactly one solution? (c) infinitely many solutions?

$$\begin{cases}
&x  &+ &y &+ &bz &= 1 \\
&bx &+ &3y &- &z &= -2 \\
&3x &+ &4y &+ &z &= c
\end{cases}
$$

my matrices look like
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -1 & b \\
        0 & 3-b & -1-b^2 \\
        0 & 1 & 1-3b \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
        x & \\
        y &\\
        z &  \\
        \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
        1 &  \\
        -2-b & \\
        c-3 & \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

How am I supposed to get this further reduced? Did I mess something up in my steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing great so far. Your reduction is correct. To reduce the matrix even more, I would swap $R_{2}$ and $R_{3}$ so that you have a more obvious pivot in column 2 and then continue row operations. I would start by subtracting $R_{1}$ from $R_{2}$, so that you can zero out row(1), col(2) and then do $R_{3}$ + (3-b)$R_{1}$ to zero out row(3), col(2). $\\$

To identify for what values of a,b,c would make the system have (a) no solution, (b) exactly one solution, or (c) infinitely many solutions you'll want to take a couple things into consideration. First, for what values of a,b,c would make your system consistent? Second, what values of a,b,c would make your system inconsistent? Once you figure that out, you will have a pretty straight-forward answer to this problem.